# How can a heap priority queue remember its index in an array?

Tags: java

What is the easiest way for me to implement this queue so that I can save each index (of where the entry is in the ArrayList heap) , in each respective MyEntry object, while not using the key or value to do so?

```
public class HeapPriorityQueue<K,V> {

protected ArrayList<Entry<K,V>> heap;
protected Comparator<K> comp;

protected static class MyEntry<K,V> implements Entry<K,V> {
    protected K key;
    protected V value;
    public MyEntry(K k, V v) {key = k; value = v;}
    public K getKey() {return key;}
    public V getValue() {return value;}
    public String toString() {return "(" + key + "," + value + ")";}
}
```

Comment: The [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) already provides this information via [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))..

Comment: If memory consumption is no problem you could use a separate `HashMap<Entry<K,V>, Integer>` that gets updated when entires are inserted. So you get in the best case a constant time `O(1)` and in the worst `O(n)`. But you could also use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) guaranteeing `O(log(n))` access time for `containsKey, get, put and remove`.

Comment: Cool yes TreeMap is what I want most def. My heap is a binary tree map. I should be able to reach O(logn) time for those functions. I need a way to store the respective index so that I do not need to iterate / search through all of the entries in my array for the desired element. How could I save the index then, could I modify the value, and make it an array , with the first element the value and second index or something similar? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What operations are provided by your heap? Insertions, Replacements or Removals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something similiar to this?

```
public class HeapPriorityQueue<K,V> {

  protected ArrayList<Entry<K,V>> heap;
  protected TreeMap<Entry<K,V>, Integer> index;
  protected Comparator<K> comp;

  public synchronized void addEntry(K key, V value) {
    // requires O(log(n))
    Entry<K, V> entry = new Entry<K, V>(key, value);
    int insertionPos = heap.size();
    heap.add(entry);
    index.put(entry, insertionPos);
  }

  public int indexOfEntry(Entry<K,V> entry ) {
    // requires O(log(n))
    return index.get(entry);
  }

  protected static class MyEntry<K,V> implements Entry<K,V> {
    protected K key;
    protected V value;
    public MyEntry(K k, V v) {key = k; value = v;}
    public K getKey() {return key;}
    public V getValue() {return value;}
    public String toString() {return "(" + key + "," + value + ")";}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! only thing is its throwing null pointer exception , not sure why.

Comment: Did you initialize all member variables in the constructor? Especially the newly introduced variable `index`..

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved Simply Using One `Map<int,int>` to Store index and Value of Array.
And One Priority `Queue<Pair<int,int>> pq` to store index and value again corresponding to priority in priority Queue.

C++ Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Author : @devangs

int main(){
    int i,j;
    vector<int> v ={1,2,3,4,5,2,5,4};
    int n=v.size();

    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mp[i]=v[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"Map With Index and Values Are: "<<endl;
    for (auto it:mp)
        cout<<it.first<<" "<<it.second<<endl;
    
    cout<<endl;
        
    cout<<"Map With Index and PQ Value Are: " <<endl;           
    priority_queue<pair<int,int>> pq; 
    for(auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++)
    {
        pq.push(make_pair(it->second, it->first));
    }
        
    while (!pq.empty()){
        cout<<pq.top().second<<" "<<pq.top().first<<endl;  
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's nice Devang, you attempted the question, however the implementation language is not same as the tag under which the question is asked. You should post this on a similar thread somewhere else where the tag is c++. If you don't find any such thread, you can even post this as a QnA style. (i.e. ask question and answer yourself)

Comment: Logic is sound and code is good, it's just not the language op asked for.